# Android : OpenGL 2.0 and repeating Textures

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, textures

Sorry if this has been asked before but I may be missing something.

If I have a object and I scale it to 25,25,25 I dont want the textures to stretch but repeat (I Believe thats GL_REPEAT)

So When I load up the texture I do

```
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,GLES20.GL_REPEAT);
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,GLES20.GL_REPEAT);
```

How this does not seem to change it.

Am I missing the function of this?

Comment: Screenshots can be really helpful.

Comment: I will try and add one, basically a cube that is 1,1,1 looks fine, but when you scale it to 25,25,25 it just stretches the texture.

Comment: if you want the texture to repeat you have to scale the texture coordinates. If your texture-coords are in the range [0,1]^2 nothing is repeated. if the range is [0,n]^2 the texture is repeated n times.